# custom message in checkout page

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, messages

How to show custom messages

[image] to certain products on **checkout page** in magento.

Comment: have a look at http://www.jyotiranjan.in/blog/add-custom-message-in-checkout-cart-page/

Comment: can you share magento version?

Comment: @Arjun i have seen jyoutiranjan blogs but his config.xml is not compled .it is hard to understand .  could you provide me some good links .so i can understand properly.........thanks

Comment: my magento version is 1.9.2.x versions

Comment: @WasimAkram I have updated your query in below answer section. I tested this changes in # Magento ver. 1.9.3.4

Answer (score 1):

@Washim Akram,

I have been updating your query with full example and tested below code in Magento ver. 1.9.3.4.[image]

file location **app/etc/modules/**

**JRB_Setcustomoption.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <JRB_Setcustomoption>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </JRB_Setcustomoption>
    </modules>
</config> 
<!--
/*
 * @category    Setcustomoption
 * @package     JRB_Setcustomoption
 * @author      Jyotiranjan Biswal <biswal@jyotiranjan.in>
 */
-->
```

File location: **app/code/local/JRB/Setcustomoption/etc**

**config.xml**

```
<!--
/*
 * @category    Setcustomoption
 * @package     JRB_Setcustomoption
 * @author      Jyotiranjan Biswal <biswal@jyotiranjan.in>
 */
-->
<config>
    <modules>
        <JRB_Setcustomoption>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </JRB_Setcustomoption>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <jrbsetcustomoption>
                <class>JRB_Setcustomoption_Model</class>
            </jrbsetcustomoption>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_load_after><!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
                <observers>
                    <jrb_setcustomoption_observer><!-- identifier of the event handler -->
                        <type>model</type><!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
                        <class>JRB_Setcustomoption_Model_Observer</class><!-- observers class alias -->
                        <method>setOption</method><!-- observer's method to be called -->
                    </jrb_setcustomoption_observer>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_load_after>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

File Location: **app/code/local/JRB/Setcustomoption/Model**

**Observer.php**

```
<?php

/*
 * Display custom message in checkout cart page
 * 
 * @category    JRB
 * @package     JRB_Setcustomoption
 * @author      Jyotiranjan Biswal <biswal@jyotiranjan.in>
 */

class JRB_Setcustomoption_Model_Observer 
{
    /*
    * Display custom message in checkout cart page
    * 
    * @category    JRB
    * @package     JRB_Setcustomoption
    * @author      Jyotiranjan Biswal <biswal@jyotiranjan.in>
    */
    public function setOption(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $action = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction();
        $params = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();

        if ($action->getFullActionName() == 'checkout_cart_add')
        {
            $product = $observer->getProduct();
            /*
            $customMessage = $product->getCustomMessage();

            //this array will acces the text message from product edit section having attribute 'custom_message'.
            $additionalOptions[] = array(
                'label' => 'My custom message',
                'value' => $customMessage,
            );
            */
            //or for static value use below code.

            $additionalOptions[] = array(
                'label' => 'My custom message',
                'value' => 'I have added a new message',
            );

            $product->addCustomOption('additional_options', serialize($additionalOptions),$product);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you jyotiranjan ..its help me a lots ..i really appreciate you..

Answer (score 0):

Add you custom message in file `app/design/frontend/{your-package}/{your-theme}/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml`

after bellow code

```
<?php if ($messages = $this->getMessages()): ?>
<?php foreach ($messages as $message): ?>
    <p class="item-msg <?php echo $message['type'] ?>">
    * <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($message['text']) ?>
    </p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Like custom message

```
<p><?php echo $this->escapeHtml('Custom message here...') ?></p>
```

Comment: @Salaam Abdul i have implemented your code but it does not work i just changed like that <?php if ($messages = $this->getMessages()): ?>
<?php foreach ($messages as $message): ?>
    <p class="item-msg <?php echo $message['type'] ?>">
    * <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($message['please add more product to get discount']) ?>
    </p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

Comment: let me know i have done right or not .if possible tell me you email id so i can contact with you.........thanks

Comment: <p class="item-msg"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml('please add more product to get discount') ?> 
</p> add after foreach

Comment: <?php if ($messages = $this->getMessages()): ?>
<?php foreach ($messages as $message): ?>
    <p class="item-msg <?php echo $message['type'] ?>">
    * <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($message['text']) ?>
    </p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php /*your custom message here..*/?>
<p class="item-msg"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml('please add more product to get discount') ?> </p>

Comment: let me show you code what i have writter plz check it once again

<?php if ($messages = $this->getMessages()): ?>
<?php foreach ($messages as $message): ?>
<p class="item-msg"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml('please add more product to get discount') ?> </p>
    <p class="item-msg <?php echo $message['type'] ?>">
    * <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($message['text']) ?>
    </p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

plz check it once

Comment: Okay check and let me know if any issues

Answer (score 0):

I took @jyotiranjan.in answer above and it works great on Magento 1.9.4

One thing I had to add though was the item note was showing up on every single product added to cart, not just ones with a custom message.

SO I added this before the output in Observer.php:

```
    if (!empty($customMessage)) {
    $product->addCustomOption('additional_options', serialize($additionalOptions),$product);}
```